# Change Azure website web hosting plan mode using Powershell

Tags: azure-web-app-service, powershell-cmdlet, azure-powershell

I've been reading the following article that describes how to change the web hosting plan for your site.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

That seems to work fine but if I use the same command to change the web hosting mode (using property: `"sku": "Free"` to `"sku": "Standard"`) it doesn't give any error feedback and just returns with the unchanged (previous) stored configuration.

Command executed:

```
$standardServer=@{"sku" = "Standard"; }
Set-AzureResource -Name 'tmtest2' -ResourceGroupName 'Default-Web-JapanWest' -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -PropertyObject $standardServer
```

Anyone had any luck changing the web hosting mode using Powershell?

**Edit**:
I also tried this link that exactly describes what I'm trying to achieve. However it did not work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654578.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured this out. You need to create a hosting plan (with 'Standard' mode) first as a resource under a default resource group. Then you need to assign the website to the hostingplan.

Here's the full script:

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager

Add-AzureAccount

$locations = @('East Asia', 'Southeast Asia', 'East US', 'East US 2', 'West US', 'North Central US', 'South Central US', 'Central US', 'North Europe', 'West Europe', 'Japan East', 'Japan West', 'Brazil South')

$websiteName = Read-Host 'What is the name of your website (without azurewebsites.net)' #tmtest2
$location = Read-Host 'What is the region location of the website'   

if (-Not($locations -contains $location)) {
 throw "location is incorrect, try one of these values: " + (($locations | select -expand $_) -join ", ")
}

$resourceGroupName = 'Default-Web-' + $location.Replace(' ', '');

#create a new web hosting plan - Small Standard machine
$hostingPlanName = $websiteName + 'HostingPlan';
$p=@{"name"= $hostingPlanName;"sku"= "Standard";"workerSize"= "0";"numberOfWorkers"= 1}
New-AzureResource -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -Name $hostingPlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverFarms -Location $location -PropertyObject $p -Verbose -Force

$r = Get-AzureResource -Name $websiteName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-04-01
echo $r

$p = $null;
$p = @{ 'serverFarm' = $hostingPlanName }
$r = Set-AzureResource -Name $websiteName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -PropertyObject $p
#echo $r.Properties

if (-Not($r.Properties['sku'] -eq 'Standard')) {
    throw 'script executed but sku has not been changed'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your Azure Resource Manager.

```
Add-AzureAccount
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
```

Get your Azure PowerShell API Version [(This link shows how)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132194/what-do-we-put-in-the-get-azureresource-apiversion-parameter/26132352#26132352)

```
$DebugPreference='Continue'
Get-AzureResourceGroup
$DebugPreference='SilentlyContinue'
```

Get the Name, ResourceGroupName, and ResourceType of your Website Resources

```
Get-AzureResource | `
Where-Object { $_.ResourceType -like '*site*' } | `
Format-Table Name, ResourceGroupName, ResourceType
```

Change the Azure Website Hosting Plan for your target Website

```
Set-AzureResource 
    -Name the-website-name
    -ResourceGroupName 'the-resource-group-name' 
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites'
    -ApiVersion '2014-04-01-preview'
    -PropertyObject @{ 'ServerFarm' = 'the-target-server-farm-name' }
```

Notes:

- You can also run `Get-AzureResource` in a similar way.
- To change the hosting plan with `Set-AzureResource`, you only need the `ServerFarm` property.