# What do we put in the Get-AzureResource -ApiVersion parameter?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to get a specific Microsoft Azure Website resource, so that I can change some of its properties. To get a single resource, `Get-AzureResource` requires the `ApiVersion` property. Where do I find this?

**Parameter Set: Get a single resource**

```
Get-AzureResource 
    [-Name] <String> 
    -ApiVersion <String> 
    -ResourceGroupName <String> 
    -ResourceType <String> 
    [-ParentResource <String> ] 
    [ <CommonParameters>]
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654579.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/03/08/how-to-quickly-determine-the-windows-azure-powershell-version.aspx)

Run the following in PowerShell.

```
$DebugPreference='Continue'
Get-AzureResourceGroup
```

The debug output will start like this:

```
DEBUG: 5:25:10 PM - GetAzureResourceGroupCommand begin processing with ParameterSet 'GetMultiple'.
DEBUG: 5:25:10 PM - using account id 'me@domain.com'...
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP REQUEST ============================

HTTP Method:
POST

Absolute Uri:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab/providers/microsoft.batch/register?api-version=2014-04-01-preview
```

Inspect the **Absolute Uri** - the query string parameter is **api-version**.

- https://management.azure.com/
- subscriptions/
- 12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab/
- providers/
- microsoft.batch/
- register?
- api-version=2014-04-01-preview

Where you're done, run the following in PowerShell to stop the debug output.

```
$DebugPreference='SilentlyContinue'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to get a particular website Resource details.

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager

$website = Get-AzureResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites" | where {$_.Name -eq "<*YOURWEBSITENAME*>"}

$websiteName = $website.Name

$websiteResource = $website.ParentResource

$websiteResourceId = $website.ResourceId
```